# Is there a RubyGem for parsing store hours?

Tags: ruby, parsing, datetime, rubygems, chronic

Are there any ruby gems to parse and standardize store hours? I've seen [Chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic), but I don't think it'll work for this specific use case.

For example, how would you parse `Mon-Sun 11am-10pm` or `Hours today: 5:30 AM – 10:00 PM`? Do you have to create rules specific to each context? Is there a library that does this already?

Comment: Have you tried using Chronic with some test cases to see if it fails? Once you have, you can write a little code to massage the values it doesn't cover into something it understands, or write your own DateTime or Time parsers using `strptime`.

Comment: Both examples failed if parsed directly with Chronic. I think the problem is that Chronic tries to identify a fixed point in time whereas these are durations. So my real question should be how can I parse a generic "duration string" into two fixed points in time.

Comment: Good point about the durations. It's not a hard nut to crack. I'll try to remember to take a look at it tonight. Basically though, `String.scan` with a short regex to retrieve the HMS and AM/PM values will be the starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Chronic Duration](https://github.com/hpoydar/chronic_duration) solves the problem of parsing duration time strings.